# Why is the tweak length 64bit in BPS FPE algorithm?

Tags: format-preserving

In the algorithm for [BPS Format Preserving Encryption](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/bps/bps-spec.pdf)

Is this tweak always the same length (64bit)?

Why did they choose the length 64bit for the tweak?

Comment: I see not leak left by: " _the 64-bit tweak value_ $T$ ". In short a tweak is an extension of the key, only not assumed secret.

Comment: @fgrieu why they choose that particular length 64 bit tweak?

Comment: 64-bit is fine for a character index, a session number..

Comment: @fgrieu I don't understand is this value independent of the internal calculations of the algorithm (like block lengths) I guess i was just wondering if the length has any significance, or is it an arbitrary number they used that is good enough for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the paper:

> We denote by $f$ the number of output bits of the internal function $F$

and

> We first divide the 64-bit tweak $T$ into two 32-bit sub-tweaks $T_L$ and $T_R$

plus

> We denote by $L_i$ (resp. $R_i$) the left (resp. right) branch value after application of round $i$.

with the note

> Note that because of our restriction on the number of input $s$-integers, we always ensure that each branch can be coded on a $(f − 32)$-bit word.

Right, so now look at part of the definition of the cipher:

> ...
>
> $L_{i+1} = L_i \boxplus F_K ((T_R \oplus i) \times 2^{f −32} + R_i) \mod s^l;$
>
> ...

although multiplication is represented by a dot instead of $\times$. Similarly for the calculation of the state $R_{i+1}$ of course.

Basically, this shifts the tweak to the most significant 32 bits, leaving the rest for the state. Now $F$ can be AES, HMAC-SHA-2 or **TDES**. TDES has a block size of 64 bit. If the tweak size was 128 bit then there would not be any space left for $R$ or $L$ that make up the internal state.

So the tweak size is such that repetition of the tweak is unlikely and it can still be used efficiently when the encryption uses a 64 bit block cipher. If the tweak would be larger the construction would become less efficient, up to the point that the scheme would not work at all.

Comment: Disclaimer: I got interested in the paper and just decided to read it...

Comment: I guess that if you would encrypt more than $2^{32}$ plaintext and you would use AES or HMAC that a larger tweak *could* be an idea. Or you could use a modern tweakable block cipher of course.

Comment: The value that gets passed into the AES function E is TR or TL XOR with round count i, multiply by 2^96.  Does this value now have 2^128 after multiplication (since TR or TL each is 2^32)?

Comment: If you mean that it should now consist of 128 bits, the block / output size of AES then: yes.

Comment: Does adding that to R ever result in a value beyond 128 bits?

Comment: Not for AES. AES without a mode of operation only handles messages that are 128 bit in size.

Comment: No I understand that, but in the formula above I mean after adding R to the tweak (before passing to the encryption function) can't addition overflow past 128 bits (if all the bits were 1)

Comment: No necause the multiplication with 2 to the power x means that x lower order bits are set to 0. If you add any value of x bits to that then you will of course not overflow. It's identical to shifting x to the left and then OR or XOR R_i into the value.